# Return last non-blank value in a row, but only if it matches the column header

Tags: excel, date

Here’s an intriguing problem. I’m creating a horizontal client log that records session dates in date format (D) and length in decimals (L).   I want to return the last value in that row (ignoring blanks) but only if that value occurs under a column header with a “D” .  My headers are:

Start /End/Hrs/D/L/D/L/D/L

Note:  Start, End & D columns are in Date format.  Hrs and L columns are in number format.

My formula for the Start Date column simply returns the value of my first D column [`=D2`]
My hours column adds alternate L columns `=SUM(E2+G2+I2)` ].

The problem formula is in my End Date column:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(D2:H2<>""),D2:H2)
```

This formula works correctly if the last entry in a row is a date [ex: 3/14/13] and returns that date to my End Date column.

Since I record session Dates and Lengths together, the last value in a row is always a decimal (Length) which returns “1/0/00” in my End Date column.  If there are no entries in that row, it returns “#N/A” which is equally unsatisfactory.

Of course, I could solve this by simply switching my Length & Date columns, but that feels strange.  The date should come first.

A clue:  if no entries is made in my first D column, it also returns a “1/0/00” in my start date column [`=D2`].  Both columns are in Date format.

Perhaps my LOOKUP formula could be nested in a match formula, but I don’t know how to do this.  Anyone up to the challenge?

With Thanks,

~ Jay

Comment: Thank you!  I tried inserting this formula into my first End Date cell, but now no entries return to it.  I'm out of my depth here.

Comment: Do I need to tell excel which row the "D" appears (over the cell with the date value I want to return)?

Comment: Like this?  =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(K6:DA6<>"")*(K$5:DA$5=”D”),K6:DA6), "")

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((D2:H2<>"")*(D$1:H$1="D")),D2:H2),"")
```